# Error Connection Refused: MailCatcher in Docker Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, mailcatcher

I have Rails application running in Docker, and I want to integrate mailcatcher for development.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
 db:
  image: postgres:alpine
  restart: always
  volumes:
   - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "9000:5432"

 app:
  build: 
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./docker/app/DockerFile
  restart: always
  command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
  volumes:
   - .:/vsapp-cms-backend
   - bundle_path:/bundle
  environment: 
    - BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle/vendor
  ports:
    - "3002:3000"
  depends_on:
    - db

 mailcatcher:
  image: schickling/mailcatcher
  ports:
    - "1080:1080"
    - "1025:1025"

volumes:
  bundle_path:
  postgres-data:
```

**development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 1025 
}
```

I can see the mailcatcher is also running on `http://localhost:1080`
but when I run  `UserMailer.send_invite(user).deliver_now!`

I'm getting

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 1025
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to send it by changing the address from **development.rb** to `mailcatcher`

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 
    address: 'mailcatcher',
    port: 1025 
}
```